# How do I delete an individual post with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a simple jobs board with Ruby on Rails for the first time and I need to work out how I would delete a job post if somebody makes an inappropriate post or it is incorrect for some reason. How would I delete just that single post?

Not sure if this code is relevant to this point but is as follows:

jobs_controller.rb -

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @jobs = Job.page(params[:page]).per(20).order(created_at: :desc)
   end

   def new
       @job = Job.new
   end

   def show
       @job = Job.find(params[:id])
   end

   def create
      @job = Job.new(params.require(:job).permit(:human_sum, :position, :company, :salary, :companywebsite, :contract, :city, :expirydate, :jobtype, :description, :apply, :contactname, :contactemail, :contactphone, ))
      if @job.save
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render "new"
      end
   end
end
```

job.rb -

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :position, presence: true
  validates :company, presence: true
  validates :salary, presence: true
  validates :companywebsite, presence: true
  validates :contract, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :expirydate, presence: true
  validates :jobtype, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :apply, presence: true
  validates :contactname, presence: true
  validates :contactemail, presence: true
  validates :contactphone, presence: true

  attr_accessor :human_sum 
  validate :not_a_bot

  private

  def not_a_bot
    if human_sum.to_i != 2 
      errors.add(:human_sum, 'Get out, you bot!') 
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb -

```
      <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
        <div class="job">
            <h2><%= link_to job.position, job %></h2>
            <br><br>
            <ul class="entry_list">
                <li>Posted on: <%= job.created_at.strftime("#{job.created_at.day.ordinalize} %B %Y") %></li>
                <li>Company: <%= job.company %></li>
                <li>Salary: <%= job.salary %></li>
                <li>Contract Type: <%= job.contract %></li>
                <li>City: <%= job.city %></li>
                <li>Applications in by: <%= job.expirydate %></li>
                <li>Job Type: <%= job.jobtype %></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <p><%= paginate @jobs %></p>
```

Comment: Exactly like you do it now. `@job.save` doesn't actually save the record if it fails validation.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I follow you?

Comment: I don't understand your quesiton.

Comment: My question is once a user has made a post, how would I delete if it wasn't suitable or appropriate?

Comment: Why don't you add a simple `delete method` in the `controller` and `link_to` for that `action` in a view

Comment: Would that mean only I would be able to delete a post and not others? I want to be the only person to be able to delete posts.

Comment: for that you need to add some role like admin or so which would be helpful. So only admin will be able to delete the posts.

Comment: Yes, thats what I would like to have. How would I go about achieving this? Sorry I'm very new to Rails.

Comment: Simplest way is probably to add `admin` boolean field to `users` table and check if one is admin before destroying record/showing link to destroy record. You can also use cancancan gem to achieve authorization. There are many possible ways and this topic is quite broad.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a admin user the simplest method will be adding a boolean field `is_admin` which can be set to true and false as @Marek Lipka said. As you need to just have a single role this will be the best way. If you need complex roles there are various gems available like `cancan`, `authority`, `rolify`. You can check any of these. In the view you can just add a simple `if` case to check if the user is admin then only the `delete` link will be visible. And to add more security to this you can add a `before_filter` in the controller for the `destroy` action in which you can check whether the user deleting the post is admin or not. If not then you can redirect him or display error message. Hope this helps.